# Trying to make question on El-Capitan and WiFi printer specific

Tags: discussion

I have an issue with my WiFi printer after upgrading my OS. I'm trying to understand/isolate (and ultimately resolve) the issue, however, I am not getting anywhere. The only question to post here that I can come up with, I myself would likely VtC as "Too Broad". But I am struggling with clarifying it.
**Should I ask anyway, or consult a discussion forum instead?**

Here's my situation:

- I use a Brother HL-2270DW printer which connects to the home WiFi.
- Previous to upgrading to OS X El Capitan on my 2009 MacBook, I had no issues using the printer.
- After upgrading the OS, the printer was gone from the list of available printers.
- The only way to add it to the list was specifying the IP address of the printer. Only then was it detected and correctly identified.
- But: I can only ever print once. On any subsequent job, the printer cannot be connected. I can delete it and add it again to the list and it will print - once.
- Adding the printer by inputting the IP address for every single document is too tedious for me.

However, as stated above, I do not know how to tackle this. And asking for trouble-shooting advice appears "too broad".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recipe for asking about troubleshooting is pretty easy once you've seen it work.

Everything is in the help section on how to ask a good question.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Just show your exact search terms on what you looked for and be narrow about the issue. You want to focus people on asking how to determine if a printer supports bonjour or how to set up a printer so that you don't have to use an IP address.

Using chat or a discussion forum might help you winnow down what you really are asking. Also, sometimes just "how can tell if printer XYZ should be discoverable by OS X version ABC" with you documenting what search you did on Apple and Brother's site makes it answerable.

Comment: Actually using your suggested search phrase brought me to the brother website which had a list of supported printers - and updated drivers. problem solved.

Comment: @Schorsch Excellent. If you wanted to contribute that knowledge here - we do encourage people to ask and then answer questions if they help accumulate specific steps to solve issues.